# Parent - Child Organisational structure

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are talking to a client who has a parent - child company structure and wants to create a GCP organisational structure that mirrors their setup such that the parent org can maintain the centralised policies and admin control but the child orgs can have their own folders yet have their own domains

Is this possible in GCP or does everything have to be under the one organisational domain? Obviously in AWS this works under the account structure as everything isnt tied to a domain

If the above isnt possible can you federate Cloud Identity with more than AD source, such that the child orgs could have folders accessible only by group?

If not are forced to create separate landing zones for each organisations with distinct domains, try and ensure policy is replicated and share services somehow (i.e via a VPC peering relationship?)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. A GCP Cloud Org can only be mapped to a single domain